# @param description showing up in code font

Tags: java-8, javadoc

I'm generating javadoc for the following simple example:

```
public class test {
  /**
   * foo does something.
   *
   * @param x the parameter
   */
  public void foo(int x) {}
}
```

I run `javadoc test.java`.

I expected `x` to have the name shown in a non-proportional font, and the description shown in a proportional font, like it happens for the official JDK javadocs for example. Instead I get what shown in this capture:

[image]

This is ok for a short description, but it's ugly for longer ones. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare the Java API documentation of `Object.equals(obj)` for [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) you will see the difference in the font for the

> #### Parameters:
>
> obj - the reference object with which to compare.

part. You will see it for all other method’s parameters as well, I just picked the well-known method as an example.

In other words, this is a general change in the behavior of JavaDoc between Java 7 and the current version of Java 8 and you are not doing anything wrong.

If you look into [the stylesheet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/stylesheet.css) you will find the definition responsible for the description part starting at line 287 containing the attribute `font-family:'DejaVu Sans Mono',monospace;`.

Comment: thanks Holger. Do you know if there is a way to drive the old style through some javadoc flag?

Comment: If you ask for a simple flag, I don’t know of such a thing. But when you create a copy of the stylesheet and modify it, you can use the `-stylesheetfile` option to tell javadoc to use your customized stylesheet.

Comment: Great answer. This can't possibly be intentional, can it? I think it must be a bug because I can't imagine anyone thinking that the descriptions look better monospaced like this. Hope they fix it in a future version. Until then I am using a customized stylesheet as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: @TypeIA this has already been fixed with JDK 9. The appearance still is different than with JDK 7 generated docs, as they use different fonts now. Compare with [`Object.equals(obj)` for Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)…